# SelectedIndexChanged Nested GridView asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, event-bubbling

I have the following code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvMaster" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="subjectid" OnRowDataBound="gvMaster_RowDataBound">
      <Columns>
           <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                     <a href="javascript:collapseExpand('subjectid-<%#Eval("subjectid") %>');"><img id="imagesubjectid-<%# Eval("subjectid") %>" alt="Click to show/hide orders" src="plus.png" /></a>
                </ItemTemplate>
           </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="strategicid" HeaderText="strategicid" HeaderStyle-CssClass="hideGridColumn" ItemStyle-CssClass="hideGridColumn" />
           <asp:BoundField DataField="subject" HeaderText="Subject" />    
           <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                     <tr>
                          <td colspan="100%">
                               <div id="subjectid-<%# Eval("subjectid") %>" style="display: none; position: relative; left: 5px;">
                                    <asp:GridView ID="nestedGridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="areaid" ClientIDMode="Static">
                                         <Columns>
                                              <asp:BoundField DataField="area" HeaderText="Area" />
                                              <asp:BoundField DataField="areaid" HeaderText="areaid" />    
                                              <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="true" ButtonType="Button" SelectText="Detail" />
                                         </Columns>
                                    </asp:GridView>
                               </div>
                          </td>
                     </tr>
                </ItemTemplate>
           </asp:TemplateField>
      </Columns>
 </asp:GridView>
```

I want to access the `nestedGridView selectedindexchanged`. I provide a `commandfield` to access the selected row. How can I do that?
Normally, I do normal thing with gridview. This is the first time I am using nestedgridview.

Answer (score 0):

In the designer go into the parent GridView’s "Edit Template" then select the nested GridView and click on the events (Lightning) in properties go into the "selected index changed" textbox and hit enter.

This will add 
`OnSelectedIndexChanged="nestedGridView_SelectedIndexChanged"` to the nested GridView and the event method `protected void nestedGridView_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)` to the code, which you could also do manually.